# Normal Variables Almost Sure Convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Ok so I got a question and I think my idea is not appropriate since those are not iid (I thought about using the Strong Law of Large Number somehow) , but I can't think about another way to solve it:

$ Let\\ X_n∼ N(7n,n)\\ and\ \\Y_n=X_n/n \\  show \ that \ Y _n ∼ L \ almost \ surely \\What\ is\ L?$

EDIT:
ok I'll specify my problem - I don't understand the almost-sure convergence term thoroughly.
Therefore I don't know what are the ways to proof that a variable converges almost surely.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well First thing is to guess what might $L$ be. So if you view $X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}$ where $Z_{i}$'s are iid $N(7,1)$ variates. Then

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}\sim N(7n,n)$.

Thus $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}\xrightarrow{a.s}7$.

Hence $X_{n}$ converges in distribution to $7$. Hence if $X_{n}$ tends almost surely to something, it must be $7$.

So Now for fixed $\epsilon$ .

$$P(|\frac{X_{n}}{n}-7|\geq \epsilon)=P(|\frac{X_{n}-7n}{n}|\geq \epsilon)=P(|\frac{X_{n}-7n}{\sqrt{n}}|\geq\epsilon\sqrt{n})=\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\epsilon\sqrt{n}}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\,dx+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon\sqrt{n}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\,dx$$

Now you have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\epsilon\sqrt{n}}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\,dx$  converges. and similarly $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon\sqrt{n}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\,dx$ converges.

Then it follows by Borel-Cantelli Lemma that $\frac{X_{n}}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s} 7$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!